# LongClick in tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

Is there a way we can add setOnLongClickListener in Tabs?? Or is there any other way where i can call one activity when clicked on a tab and a different activity when long clicked on the same tab??

```
public class HelloTabWidget extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Resources res = getResources(); 
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); 
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;
        Intent intent;  

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, ArtistsActivity.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("artists").setIndicator("Artists",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);


        tabHost.addTab(spec);
        tabHost.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
////                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LongClickStuff.class);
//              startActivity(i);
//              return true;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "into long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return false;
            }

        });


        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, AlbumsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("albums").setIndicator("Albums",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SongsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("songs").setIndicator("Songs",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested and verified where "0" is the index of the tab to be long clicked:

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "long click", 1).show();
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well hells bells.  I just ran the code.  It works, but for a long click of the tab view not the tab itself.  Interesting ...

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there no way I can make the tab clickable and not the view??

Comment: The view is still long clickable?

Comment: the view is long clickable but the problem is when i take my finger off of it, the long clicked activity starts and when that activity exits, tab detects a normal click because of the previous long click and then starts the activity it is supposed to when clicked normally..

Comment: I'll give it another look.  Might take me a few days ... moving.

Comment: One more issue is (If u dont mind) how not to make it "highlightable" when long clicked??Coz if I long click all of them one after the other all of them remain highlighted altogether.. So how do I get rid of the highlight..