# android Kotlin: tab long click listener

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout

I am struggling with how to implement a long click on my tabs. I have tried a few different things however none seem to work.

I am sure maybe its something basic or I simply am not understanding the on clicks with the tablayout and pager.

I have found some questions on here but they do are not referring to on long click.

here are a few of the things that I have tried.

```
    main_tab_pager.iterator().forEach {
        view ->
        view.setOnLongClickListener{
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            true
        }
   main_tabs.setOnLongClickListener { 
        when(main_tabs.selectedTabPosition) {
            0-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            1-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            2-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        true 
    }

    main_tab_pager.setOnLongClickListener {
        when(main_tab_pager.currentItem) {
            0-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 0", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            1-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            2-> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
        true
    }
```

tab/pager setup code.

```
main_tab_pager.adapter = TabAdapter(supportFragmentManager, sections)
    main_tabs.setupWithViewPager(main_tab_pager)
```

tab adapter

```
class TabAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, private val sections: 
Array<BaseFragment>) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager) 
{
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return sections[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return sections.size
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return sections[position].title
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6050655/2751783

Comment: Since you're doing `setupWithViewPager()`, about the only way to do this (without modifying `TabLayout`) is to manually iterate over the tab `View`s, and set the `OnLongClickListener` on each one. However, those `View`s are not direct children of the `TabLayout`. They are nested inside another `View`, so you'd have to iterate over the children of the first child of the `TabLayout`.

Comment: @MikeM. ok that is fine however how would I do that? I seem to be able to get the child using main_tabs[0] or getchildat(0) but it doesn't seem to produce a view group to iterate over.

Comment: You'll have to cast it to `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. i figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

Solution thanks to Mike M.

```
   val tabs = main_tabs.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout

    for (i in 0 until tabs.childCount) {
        when(i){
            0 -> tabs.getChildAt(0).setOnLongClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "tab 0 ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true
            }
            1 -> tabs.getChildAt(1).setOnLongClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "tab 1", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true
            }
            2 -> tabs.getChildAt(2).setOnLongClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(baseContext, "tab 2", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                true
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `as ViewGroup` would be sufficient. It does happen to be a `LinearLayout` subclass, but that might change in other versions. Just FYI. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
val tabs = recylerbin_tabLayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
for (i in 0 until tabs.childCount) {
            tabs.getChildAt(i).setOnLongClickListener {
                true
            }
        }
}
```